# Can I upgrade the video card of a Dell Studio XPS 16?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

The Studio XPS 16 comes with either integrated Intel graphics, or discrete ATI graphics. Would I be able to replace the card with, say, an nVidia GeForce 8800M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://en.community.dell.com/forums/t/19287806.aspx)

> No, the video cannot be upgraded - it is part of the system board.
>   If you want the ATI 4670 video, be sure you order the system with it.