# Is it possible to upgrade the onboard graphics card of HP1000 Laptop?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

For a HP1000 laptop, there is onboard graphics of `intel (R) HD graphics 3000`. So, I think it is not enough to play big games like the `Blur` game. So, was thinking whether I could add an additional card to it. But I was not sure whether it is possible. Because for a desktop machine, we could do that easily. But this a laptop that I am talking about.

So, am looking for answers from experts like you.

Thank you

Comment: I would be very glad if the down voter could atleast post a comment regarding his down vote! I already searched in google before posting and was found in some other forums that it is not possible. Since I was unsure, I wanted to get a direct answer from the experts. That's why I posted it here. BTW, I don't own a laptop(till date only have a desktop for working). This laptop question was just a doubt.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this question is perilously close to a dup (but not quite) .  See http://superuser.com/questions/428228/how-do-i-upgrade-my-graphics-on-my-laptop/428237#428237, http://superuser.com/questions/1862/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-the-graphics-card-in-modern-laptops/233970#233970, http://superuser.com/questions/1862/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-the-graphics-card-in-modern-laptops, http://superuser.com/questions/68604/can-i-upgrade-the-video-card-of-a-dell-studio-xps-16, http://superuser.com/questions/120767/can-a-graphics-card-nvidia-be-added-to-a-laptop/120778#120778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vast majority of modern (including yours) laptops have built in GPUs on the motherboard. The only exceptions are expensive gaming laptops, usually custom build for purpose.

With most laptops you simply don't have anywhere to put new components like this. Not to mention the case they are housed in won't allow for additional devices sticking out without some modification.

Answer (score 3):

With Intel HD Graphics, the GPU is built into the processor itself. Because of this, motherboards with integrated graphics aren't designed for an aftermarket GPU.

Even if the original laptop had the option of a discrete GPU, the manufacturer has different motherboards specially designed with those GPU's already integrated/soldered into them.

With laptops, the only time you can change the GPU on them is when you are ordering them and request an upgraded one.

Comment: I wanted to accept both Bob's and Mathew's as accepted answers. Since only one can be marked as answer, I am marking Mathew's as the answer since he told it first. And am giving you upvote

Comment: `With laptops, the only time you can change the GPU on them is when you are ordering them and request an upgraded one.` or when they have a MXM slot.   (for partial completeness sake, and ignoring external graphics cards)